# how to range letter aa to zz

Tags: python-3.x

with open('platenon.txt', 'w') as f:
   for platecode in range(1000):
    upper_chars = [chr(platecode).upper() for platecode in range(ord('aa'), ord('zz')+1)]
    f.write('KJA{0:03d:upper_chars}\n'.format(platecode))

Comment: Please use code formatting and explain your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "with" which automatically close your file

```
with open('platenon.txt', 'w') as f:
   for platecode in range(100):
       f.write('KJA{0:03d}AA'.format(platecode))
```

Comment: If you want to have a newline after every line you can use the character '\n' at the end of the string ('KJS{0:03d}AA\n')